# Is it safe to return parameter that was passed by reference?

Tags: c#, reference, return, pass-by-reference

I'm usually working with C++, where returning a function argument that was passed as a reference can lead to problems (like a dangling reference or perhaps UB.) Does something similar hold true in C#?

Case in point:

```
byte[] do_something(byte[] arg)
{
    byte[] ret = null;

    // ...
    // Some of the code paths can lead to:
    ret = arg;

    // ...

    return ret;
}
```

Now the caller of the above method does:

```
byte[] array = // ...
array = do_something(array);
```

Is this always safe in C#, or are there cases where it leads to trouble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the parameter was *passed by reference* then this would be something to think about, yes.  (At least, if you're doing that you're returning a copy of the current value of the variable, you're not returning the reference, so the reference semantics are lost.)  If it was a *reference type passed by value* then it's not a problem at all.

In your case you have a *reference type passed by value*, so there is no problem returning it.

In C++, in this situation you'd need to be concerned about when the pointer you passed in should be deleted.  If the caller doesn't know if the returned pointer is the same as the one passed in they don't know if they need to defer deleting either pointer until uses of both are done.  Of course in C# this is a moot point as the developer never needs to worry about deleting pointers at all; the Garbage Collector will take care of it.

If this were an `IDisposable` object then you would need to be a bit worried.  If you were in this situation you'd need to ensure that all disposable objects are disposed of, and none are never disposed of.  This pattern of passing in a disposable object and either getting itself, or possibly a new disposable object back, would be...concerning.  It'd avoid that pattern if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks, especially for pointing out reference types passed by value. I'm still somewhat new to C# and didn't know that `arg` in this case isn't actually a reference :-)